# The textfield in not updating flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, bottom-sheet

I am creating app where i have used ShowModelBottomSheet where i created two tab bars
I used these to edit my record
Like when user press on edit button the bottom sheet open and the record already present there in text fields
But the issue is when I change the text the text revert back to original text before updating.
I have created another bottomsheet to add record and that works fine

here is my code can anyone please tell me how to overcome

```
  bool _editAdvanceUpArrow = false;
  bool _editTextFieldUpArrow = false;
  bool _editIncomeTextFieldUpArrow = false;
  bool _editIncomeAdvanceUpArrow = false;
  bool editIncomeTogle = false;
  final editExpenseForm = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final editIncomeForm = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool editTogle = true;
  TextEditingController editLabel = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController editAmount = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController editDescription = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode editLabeFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode editAmmountFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode editDescriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();

  void editBottomSheet(BudgetRecord record) {
    int initialTabIndex = (record.type.toLowerCase() == 'expense') ? 0 : 1;
    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 15,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return DefaultTabController(
              length: 2,
              initialIndex: initialTabIndex,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10,
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Image.asset('assets/bottomSheetBar.png'),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    TabBar(
                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                      indicatorColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                      unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.lightTextColor,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Image.asset('assets/expense_tab_logo.png'),
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              const Text(
                                'Expense',
                                style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.expenseColor),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Image.asset('assets/income_tab_logo.png'),
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              const Text(
                                'Income',
                                style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.incomeColor),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 440,
                      child: TabBarView(
                        children: [
                          editExpenseTabContent(setState, record),
                          editIncomeTabContent(setState, record),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget editExpenseTabContent(StateSetter setState, BudgetRecord record) {
    editLabel.text = record.label;
    editAmount.text = record.amount;
    editDescription.text = record.description;
    String formattedDate =
        CommonData.formatDateForEdit(record.date ?? record.createdAt);
    String formattedTime = CommonData.formatTimeForEdit(
        record.date ?? record.createdAt, record.time ?? record.createdAt);
    editTogle = record.done;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 28.0, vertical: 65),
          child: Form(
            key: editExpenseForm,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(30),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                          focusNode: editLabeFocusNode,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Field is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          controller: editLabel,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                          },
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                          cursorColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _editTextFieldUpArrow =
                                          !_editTextFieldUpArrow;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  icon: _editTextFieldUpArrow
                                      ? Image.asset('assets/up_arrow.png')
                                      : Image.asset('assets/down_arrow.png')),
                              labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              hintText: 'Label',
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                              border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(30),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                          focusNode: editAmmountFocusNode,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Field is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          controller: editAmount,
                          keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                          inputFormatters: [
                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                          ],
                          cursorColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              hintText: 'Amount',
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(30),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                          focusNode: editDescriptionFocusNode,
                          controller: editDescription,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                          cursorColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              hintText: 'Description',
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 35,
                            child: TextButton.icon(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _editAdvanceUpArrow = !_editAdvanceUpArrow;
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: _expenseAdvanceUpArrow
                                    ? Image.asset('assets/up_arrow.png')
                                    : Image.asset('assets/down_arrow.png'),
                                label: const Text(
                                  'Advance',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.mainColor,
                                  ),
                                )),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              const Text('Paid ?'),
                              Switch(
                                  activeColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                                  activeTrackColor:
                                      const Color.fromARGB(200, 124, 183, 191),
                                  inactiveThumbColor: AppColors.lightTextColor,
                                  inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
                                  value: editTogle,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      editTogle = !editTogle;
                                    });
                                  }),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      _editAdvanceUpArrow
                          ? Column(
                              children: [
                                GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () => _selectDate(context, setState),
                                  child: AbsorbPointer(
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                          labelText: 'Date'),
                                      controller: TextEditingController(
                                          text: formattedDate),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () => _selectTime(context, setState),
                                  child: AbsorbPointer(
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                          labelText: 'Time'),
                                      controller: TextEditingController(
                                          text: formattedTime),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: _editAdvanceUpArrow ? 20 : 15,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          final recordd = BudgetRecord(
                              uuid: record.uuid,
                              type: 'Expense',
                              label: editLabel.text,
                              description: editDescription.text,
                              amount: editAmount.text,
                              done: editTogle,
                              createdAt:
                                  DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String(),
                              addedBy: UserData().id,
                              device: Platform.isAndroid ? 'Android' : "IOS",
                              date: date.isEmpty ? null : date,
                              time: time.isEmpty ? null : time,
                              updatedAt:
                                  DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String(),
                              deletedAt: "");
                          addEditIRecord(recordd, true);
                          CommonData.saveDataToMonthlyBudgetPrefrences(
                              UserData().budget, UserData().email);
                          setState(() {
                            _editAdvanceUpArrow = false;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            editLabel.clear();
                            editAmount.clear();
                            editDescription.clear();
                          });
                          CommonData.showCustomSnackbar(
                              context, 'Record updated Successfully');
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          elevation: 5, backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                          minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(55), // NEW
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                          "Update",
                          style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.tabsColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        if (_editTextFieldUpArrow)
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 60),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
              child: Container(
                height: 250,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: expenseLabelList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final name = expenseLabelList[index];
                    return Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            editLabel.text = name;
                            _editTextFieldUpArrow = !_editTextFieldUpArrow;
                          });
                        },
                        child: ListTile(
                            leading: Text(
                          name,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: AppColors.darkTextColor, fontSize: 15),
                        )),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to not update your text editing controller values inside editExpenseTabContent().
Or create a stateful class for editExpenseTabContent instead of method and update values in

```
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
 }
```